# How many words can we make from the alphabet {a, b, c, d} of length 6?

Tags: combinatorics

How many words can we make from the alphabet {a, b, c, d} of length 6?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Use [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\_\ \_\ \_\ \_\ \_\ \_$ be any word of length six formed from the letters $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. Then there are four possibilities for each of the six letters of the word, and hence there are
$$
4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 = 4^6 = 4096
$$
words in total.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.